# How to flash STM32 via Serial Port

Tags: linux, embedded, microcontroller, stm32

I have an STM32F102 microcontroller and I want to program it via the Serial Port.

While there is a flasher available for windows, I want to do it on a Linux Machine. I tried doing it with this script

I have set BOOT0 = 1 and BOOT1 = 0, restarted the microcontroller. But it does not work. I get the following output

```
Can't init. Ensure BOOT0=1, BOOT1=0, and reset device
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stm32loader.py", line 552, in <module>
    bootversion = cmd.cmdGet()
  File "stm32loader.py", line 140, in cmdGet
    if self.cmdGeneric(0x00):
  File "stm32loader.py", line 137, in cmdGeneric
    return self._wait_for_ack(hex(cmd))
  File "stm32loader.py", line 88, in _wait_for_ack
    raise CmdException("No response to %s" % info)
__main__.CmdException: No response to 0x0
```

Comment: I think this will be impossible to reproduce without having access to your specific system. There could be numerous causes for the problem.

Comment: Is there any other utility that would help me program the microcontroller? I may as well try that...

Comment: Why use a serial port? Use some JTAG adapter, goes much faster and is more reliable.

Comment: During the prototyping I did it via ST-Link. But now the boards do not have a functionality for ST-Link. Hence Serial Programming.

Comment: Can you program it on Windows? Can you program the prototyping board trough the serial port?

Comment: I do not have Windows. I will find a pc and get back here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are a few tips:

- Connect serial cable before resetting / powering up the board. Otherwise some transients can mess the serial bootloader up.
- Make sure you are using a TTL level USB-to-serial converter instead of a RS-232 cable. RS-232 has inverted level, and worse still, its -15V to 15V voltage range can burn your STM32.
- Make sure RX and TX are connected correctly.
- Try using [`stm32flash`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/stm32flash/) instead.
- Most STM32's serial bootloader does not support baud rate higher than 115200 as I remember. The bootloader can detect baud rate automatically, the one I usually use is 57600.

Answer (score 0):

Some of these chips are being shipped with locked bootloaders. You will need to use [STM32 Flash loader demonstrator](http://www.st.com/en/development-tools/flasher-stm32.html) to remove the protection. Windows only unfortunately but once it is unlocked you can use any machine.